# Disable cache in WebSVN

Tags: cache, svn

I am using WebSVN.

It is quite cool but its cache directory is 6GB!

I would like to disable the cache (which is not very important for my application) or, at least, limit it.

I have checked the configuration file in in include/config.php but I haven't found the way.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/websvn/config.php
```

comment the line with  `setCachingOn()` in it.